# Settings "pop-up" WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know how to name this, but the purpose is to when I click the right mouse button and then the left button right after (without opening the popup that usually opens with the right mouse button), it should popup this "settings menu" with an animation like this one:

[image: Circle Entrance Animation]

or just a "size in". If it is not possible or its to complicate to open with the mouse buttons, it could be done with any key/combination from the keyboard.

Anyone has any idea how I could do this? Im using C# WPF and Blend.

[image: Idea (Center circle has 30% transparency, outer has 5%)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have a partial answer for you. You can use a Radial Menu as the popup. There are many paid Radial Menu controls, but [this](https://github.com/Julien-Marcou/RadialMenu) (nugget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RadialMenu.WPF/)) one seems open source and looks good (I haven't used it).

Regarding that loading animation, Expression Drawing might have a convenient Arc drawing to do that.

```
<ed:Arc x:Name="arc" Stretch="None" Height="64" Width="64" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" EndAngle="360" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5" StartAngle="0" />
```

And a simple storyboard can animate it.

```
<Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ed:Arc.EndAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arc">
              <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
              <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="360"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Visual Studio Blend should help you do it very easily.

Comment: That is exatly the kinda thing i wanted! It solves 90% of the problem, ty!
I'll try to implement it on my application